# Color distortion setting QFrame background

Tags: python, pyqt

I am leaning Python and PyQT, while leaning I would like to make something out of it.
The following code reads pixels on the screen, and display it within the GUI. But the color is distorted. Would you kindly let me know what is the problem? Also could you give me a point where to start, if I want to create a Qthread that continuously updates the mouse position on the GUI. Sample code will be great, it doesn't need to be complete just something get me started on QThread. Thank you for your help.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL

import ctypes
from ctypes import c_int32, c_uint32, c_void_p, c_wchar_p, pointer, POINTER


GetDC = ctypes.windll.User32.GetDC
GetDC.argtypes = [c_void_p]
GetDC.restype = c_void_p

ReleaseDC = ctypes.windll.User32.ReleaseDC
ReleaseDC.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p] #hwnd, hdc
ReleaseDC.restype = c_int32

GetPixel = ctypes.windll.Gdi32.GetPixel
GetPixel.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int32, c_int32] # hdc, x, y
GetPixel.restype = c_uint32 # colorref

MAXWIDTH = 100
MAXHIGH = 28

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_ColorPicker(object):
    def setupUi(self, ColorPicker):
        ColorPicker.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ColorPicker"))
        ColorPicker.resize(618, 310)


        self.PixelArray = []

        self.cbAlwaysOnTop = QtGui.QCheckBox(ColorPicker)
        self.cbAlwaysOnTop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 91, 17))
        self.cbAlwaysOnTop.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cbAlwaysOnTop"))
        self.cbAlwaysOnTop.connect(self.cbAlwaysOnTop,SIGNAL("toggled(bool)"), self.AlwaysOnTop)

        # Creating the Pixel Array
        PixelDisplayY = 35
        for i in range(0, MAXHIGH - 1):
            PixelDisplayX = 10
            self.PixelArray.append([])
            for j in range(0, MAXWIDTH - 1):
                #pixel = QtGui.QFrame(ColorPicker)
                pixel = ScreenPixel(ColorPicker)
                pixel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(PixelDisplayX, PixelDisplayY, 5, 5))
                pixel.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                pixel.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
                pixel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame"))
                pixel.setAutoFillBackground(True)
                pal = QtGui.QPalette(pixel.palette())
                pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window,QtGui.QColor('green'))
                #pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window,QtGui.QColor(cc.rgbResult))
                pixel.setPalette(pal)
                self.PixelArray[i].append(pixel)
                PixelDisplayX = PixelDisplayX + 6
            PixelDisplayY = PixelDisplayY + 6

        #pal = QtGui.QPalette(pixel.palette())
        #pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window,QtGui.QColor('white'))
        #self.PixelArray[1][2].setPalette(pal)

        self.edResult = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(ColorPicker)
        self.edResult.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 600, 71))
        self.edResult.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plainTextEdit"))

        self.pbStart = QtGui.QPushButton(ColorPicker)
        self.pbStart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pbStart.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pbStart"))
        self.pbStop = QtGui.QPushButton(ColorPicker)
        self.pbStop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pbStop.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pbStart_2"))
        self.pbAll = QtGui.QPushButton(ColorPicker)
        self.pbAll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pbAll.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pbStart_3"))

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(ColorPicker)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 200, 61, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.edPosX = QtGui.QLineEdit(ColorPicker)
        self.edPosX.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 200, 60, 20))
        self.edPosX.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.edPosX.setText("0")
        self.edPosX.connect(self.edPosX,SIGNAL("editingFinished()"), self.UpdatePixelArray)
        self.edPosY = QtGui.QLineEdit(ColorPicker)
        self.edPosY.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 200, 60, 20))
        self.edPosY.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.edPosY.setText("0")
        self.edPosY.connect(self.edPosY,SIGNAL("editingFinished()"), self.UpdatePixelArray)
        self.edPosW = QtGui.QLineEdit(ColorPicker)
        self.edPosW.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 200, 60, 20))
        self.edPosW.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_3"))
        self.edPosW.setText("100")
        self.edPosW.connect(self.edPosW,SIGNAL("editingFinished()"), self.UpdatePixelArray)
        self.edPosH = QtGui.QLineEdit(ColorPicker)
        self.edPosH.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 200, 60, 20))
        self.edPosH.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_4"))
        self.edPosH.setText("28")
        self.edPosH.connect(self.edPosH,SIGNAL("editingFinished()"), self.UpdatePixelArray)


        self.retranslateUi(ColorPicker)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ColorPicker)

    def retranslateUi(self, ColorPicker):
        ColorPicker.setWindowTitle(_translate("ColorPicker", "Color Picker", None))
        self.cbAlwaysOnTop.setText(_translate("ColorPicker", "Always On Top", None))
        self.pbStart.setText(_translate("ColorPicker", "Start", None))
        self.pbStop.setText(_translate("ColorPicker", "Stop", None))
        self.pbAll.setText(_translate("ColorPicker", "All", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("ColorPicker", "(X,Y,W,H)", None))

    def AlwaysOnTop(self):
        if self.cbAlwaysOnTop.isChecked():
            ColorPicker.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            ColorPicker.show()
        else:
            ColorPicker.setWindowFlags(ColorPicker.windowFlags() & ~ QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            ColorPicker.show()

    def __getPixelColor(self, x, y):
        hdc = GetDC(0)
        val = GetPixel(hdc, x, y)
        ReleaseDC(0, hdc)
        return val

    def UpdatePixelArray(self): 
        x = int(self.edPosX.text())
        y = int(self.edPosY.text())
        w = int(self.edPosW.text())
        h = int(self.edPosH.text())

        cc = CHOOSECOLOR()

        if int(x) < 0:
            x = 0
            self.edPosX.setText("0")
        if int(y) < 0:
            y = 0
            self.edPosY.setText("0")
        if int(w) > MAXWIDTH:
            w = MAXWIDTH
            self.edPosW.setText("100")
        if int(h) > MAXHIGH:
            h = MAXHIGH
            self.edPosH.setText("28")

        for i in range(0, MAXHIGH - 1):
            for j in range(0, MAXWIDTH - 1):
                pixel = self.PixelArray[i][j]
                pal = QtGui.QPalette(pixel.palette())
                pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window,QtGui.QColor('green'))
                self.PixelArray[i][j].setPalette(pal)
                self.PixelArray[i][j].staticColor = False

        for i in range(0, h - 1):
            for j in range(0, w - 1):
                cc.rgbResult = self.__getPixelColor(j+x, i+y)
                pixel = self.PixelArray[i][j]
                pal = QtGui.QPalette(pixel.palette())
                pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window,QtGui.QColor(cc.rgbResult))
                self.PixelArray[i][j].setPalette(pal)
                self.PixelArray[i][j].cc = cc
                self.PixelArray[i][j].posX = j + x
                self.PixelArray[i][j].posY = i + y    

class CHOOSECOLOR(ctypes.Structure):
         _fields_ = [('lStructSize', c_uint32),
                     ('hwndOwner', c_void_p),
                     ('hInstance', c_void_p),
                     ('rgbResult', c_uint32),
                     ('lpCustColors',POINTER(c_uint32)),
                     ('Flags', c_uint32),
                     ('lCustData', c_void_p),
                     ('lpfnHook', c_void_p),
                     ('lpTemplateName', c_wchar_p)]

class ScreenPixel(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.cc = CHOOSECOLOR
        self.posX = 0
        self.posY = 0
        self.staticColor = False
        return super().__init__(parent)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ColorPicker = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_ColorPicker()
    ui.setupUi(ColorPicker)
    ColorPicker.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please clarify "distorted". Also, please create a separate question for the QThread question: when you do, clarify "continuously updates the mouse position", as the two obvious ways of interpreting this don't require thead.